# Keep back-link power when a site frequently changes domain name due to getting blocked

Tags: seo, domains, backlinks

In my case, my domain will change regularly because streaming sites are always blocked from time to time,

Info:

- all site structure is same, just change domain
- domainA = first domain
- domain b,c,d,e = new domain for replace domainA

**Which method is good keep backlink power with low cost:**

1. just need to focus give a backlink to domainA, right even though it's already blocked by isp and only used for 301 redirects to domain b,c,d,e every time it is blocked?
2. backlink to current active domain,
   example:

current domain: domainB ( already backlinking to this domain ),

> domainA redirect (301) with old backlink to domainB and when domainB blocked,

> Create new backlink todomainC. and redirect all domain A & B (301) to C ( this method will
> be very inconvenient, because you have to extend a lot of old unused
> domains  )

3.Any suggestion?

I read some article say redirect 301 will pass backlink but not 100%,
and currently i'm using method 1, but in gsc all backlinks detect anchor with post title name or description from old domain, will it hurt or decrease in seo value?

Example:

> domain-backlinkA with anchor "SEO" point to old domainA, but when
> domainA redirect to DomainB anchor will changed to post title or
> description.

Comment: Who is doing the blocking?  Is it Google removing the site from the search results.

Comment: Normally Blocked by isp, but i also need to know both if can :)
#i edit post with new question

Comment: What are the reasons that ISPs block your site?  Is this a "they don't like the competition" situation or a copyright infringement situation, or a government censorship situation?

Answer (score 3):

### Ultimately, if you want to rank for searches it would be best to stop getting banned so you can keep a domain.

If your streaming site has to change domains frequently from getting blocked, I think it's safe to assume that your traffic is likely 100% direct or referral. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

If you're not getting taken down by Google, but you *are* getting ISP blocks...that probably means that Google hasn't found you (or found *out* about you) yet.

Boosting your PageRank ("back link power") will help pages on your site rank higher on search result pages (SERPs). In other words, it will *help* Google find your site.

Are you *sure* that you *want* to be found by Google?

Assuming I'm correct about why you're getting blocked in the first place, for a streaming site like yours, PageRank is **not important**. If you're looking to increase users, I'd look at more traditional/word of mouth avenues.

Otherwise, as I stated in my headline, you need to stop getting banned for SEO to be possible.

Comment: only 30-40% direct traffic, and i aim organic traffic, even getting take down by google i still aim organic. every week release new episode i only need rank this episode even only 1 day,

if using mouth to mouth also not good, how if blocked by isp and new user don't know about new domain, they will search new site in google.

anyway I'm still looking for the best option to maintain backlinks to rank on google in the new domain

Comment: Even so, if a user searches for the new site on Google, as long as your new domain is _indexed_ they'll find you. You don't need PageRank to be indexed. That's going to be an exact match search. What other sites are going to be competing?

Comment: 1. how about aiming for rank in every new episode?
2. so much competitor using same name brand only different tld, so higher rank will get more traffic. that's why this is important in my case to keep backlink power

Comment: If you want to rank for searches stop getting banned so you can keep a domain.

Comment: I think that last comment is the real answer.  I really doubt there is a way to have good SEO if your domain name keeps changing due to bans.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yeah agreed. I've edited my original.

Comment: Not getting blocked is maybe easier said than done though.  I've asked the OP why ISPs would be blocking the site.  I know Netflix has gotten blocked by ISPs, but they never changed their domain to get around it.